# Parameterize multiple OR in the where clause of a query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to parameterize this:

`select * from myTable where column1='1' or TaxRateRef='18'`

into something like this:

```
String query = "select * from myTable where "; // column1='1' or column1='18'

var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count;i++)
{
   blah blah blah

   query += " Column1='@column1' or";

   parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column1", i));

 }
```

however I get an exception

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException :The variable name '@column1' has already been declared.Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
Incorrect syntax near 'or'.
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that gets executed after forming the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is obvious. You are adding the parameter too many times in that `for` loop. You should add this line...

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column1", i));
```

only once in your query. If you need to add a different value on each iteration of the loop, simply append the iteration number(`i`) to the parameter name in order to make it unique...

```
 query += string.Format(" Column1='@column1{0}' or", i);
 parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(string.Format("@column1{0}", i), i));
```

Comment: Yup - although I guess then the "1" isn't needed. ;)

Comment: @RobFarley absolutely. I just copied/pasted...the point is that `parameters.Add` declares a new parameter in the sql batch and parameter names must be unique within a batch...it's like declaring two variables in `C#` with the same name within the same scope

Comment: Yes. Your code is valid - I was writing similar when your comment appeared. But then I noticed the "1" still in there and thought I'd point it out in case the OP got confused.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is because of `@column1` appending all the time. use the below one

```
parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(string.Format("@column1{0}", i), i));

String query = "select * from myTable where "; // column1='1' or column1='18'

var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

for(int i = 0; i < data.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  blah blah blah

  query += " Column1='@column1' or";

  parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@column1", i));
  parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(string.Format("@column1{0}", i), i));

}
```